# Looking for equals in nested collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `IEnumerable` collections (BaseCollectionA & BaseCollectionB).

Items of these collections are other collections (SubCollectionA & SubCollectionB).
The SubCollections can have one or more collection items (objects) in them.
The SubCollections contain objects (MyObject) with my properties;

I would like to compare the two BaseCollections and their SubCollections' items (MyObjects) for duplicates, i.e. return **true when there is an item (MyObject) in any of SubCollections of BaseCollectionA that is equal to an item (MyObject) in any of SubCollections of BaseCollectionB.**

```
IEnumerable<T> BaseCollectionA
{
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionA1,
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionA2,
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionA3,
    ...
}

IEnumerable<T> BaseCollectionB
{
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionB1,
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionB2,
    IEnumerable<T> SubCollectionB3,
    ...
}
```

Performance is very important in my case therefore it would be best to have the fastest possible solution. Also, I prefer writing linq in method syntax.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: SelectMany might be of use

Comment: Your question is not well stated. Also show us your code before asking others to write it for you.

Comment: Equal in what sense?  By reference or by virtue of one or more key matching MyObject properties?

Answer (score -1):

```
var allTsInA = baseCollectionA.Concat(baseCollectionA.SubCollectionA1)
                              .Concat(baseCollectionA.SubCollectionA2)
                              .Concat(baseCollectionA.SubCollectionA3);

var allTsInB = /* same for B */;

var result = allTsInA.Any(allTsInB.Contains);
```

You may want to improve that a little bit by maybe using Dictionaries or HashSets instead of iterating all over again if you do it multiple times.